# Function returning 'None'

Tags: python

I'm working on a problem using Python. Here's the concerned code for the problem I'm about to explain:

```
def no_to_words(n):
    num = str(n)
    s = ""
    if(len(num) == 3):
        hunds = n/100
        ten = n%100
        tens = ten/10
        units = ten%10
        if(n == 100):
            return "one hundred"

        if(hunds == 1):                        
            s = s + "one hundred and"
        elif(hunds == 2):
            s = s + "two hundred and"
        elif(hunds == 3):
            s = s + "three hundred and"
        elif(hunds == 4):
            s = s + "four hundred and"
        elif(hunds == 5):
            s = s + "five hundred and"
        elif(hunds == 6):
            s = s + "six hundred and"
        elif(hunds == 7):
            s = s + "seven hundred and"
        elif(hunds == 8):
            s = s + "eight hundred and"
        else:
            s = s + "nine hundred and"

        def final(t):
            ans = t
            return ans
        if(ten == 11):                         
            s = s + " eleven"
            final(s)

print no_to_words(111)
```

Now, this function converts a three-digit number into it's alphabetic equivalent string(I haven't posted the whole code here). Now, if a number like '111' is the input, then the value of 'ten' would be 11. That means, the new value of 's' would now be 'one hundred and eleven'. So for returning this value and preventing the program to go further and check for the 'units' value(the code for which is not included here), I tried calling the 'final' function, with 's' as parameter. And what the 'final' function does is that it returns the value of 's'.

However, with '111' as input, I get 'None' as my output. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You should really consider using a list/s for this. It will really bring down the character count for such a simple code. :)

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or 3? If it's Python 3, you will need to change your `/`s to either `//` or `int(x/y)`. Otherwise, for example, `111/100` = `1.11` which is not what you want.

Comment: Do note that "and" is not used when writing numbers in word form.  So 512 becomes "five hundred twelve" not "five hundred *and* twelve".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it may look right, you don't actually properly `return` something for every outcome.

Although `111` fulfils a condition at the end (`111 / 10 == 11`, `if ten == 11`) you don't actually return a value for it.

To fix this, you need to do:

```
return final(s)  # If you don't return it here, you are just throwing it away.
```

to `return` something for that branch. Although at the moment you are calling `final` which returns a value, it is in a deeper scope (it will only `return` to the caller). To return from the overall function, you need to 'return the returned value' if that makes sense.

---

Also, the reason you get `None` is because when there is no returned value, it is equivalent to returning `None`, so that is your output.

Comment: How come '111' doesn't fulfill any of the conditions in the program? The 'ten' value is '11', and so shouldn't it call the 'final' function?

Comment: final(s) returns a value but only to itself. no_to_words doesn't actually return anything. You need to `return s` and just remove the final part.

Comment: I also don't understand the purpose of OP's function final().  It takes an argument, assigns it to a different variable, then returns the same thing.

Comment: He's confused about the use of return, that's all

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I could do the same thing by returning 's' instead of calling a new function. Thanks a ton everyone ! Still a newbie, learning every day :)

Comment: I hope part of that learning process is marking an answer as accepted if it solved your problem. ;)

Comment: It says that I still have to wait for 5 more minutes before I could accept an answer. I sure will as soon as Stackoverflow allows me to

Answer (score 4):

You ignore the output of the `final()` function:

```
if(ten == 11):                         
    s = s + " eleven"
    final(s)
```

Just because `final()` returns something doesn't mean your outer function will return too. A nested function is like any other function, it returns *to the caller only*.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `final()` it returns a value but you don't return that value.

```
return final(s)
```

or simply

```
return s
```

Answer (score 3):

`111 % 10 = 11`.

In your `if ten == 11:` branch you don't return a value. You need to `return final(s)`

Also the parens around the if statements aren't needed in python and you should generally remove them.